# saber la longitud de una tabla de MySQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito saber la longitud de una tabla MySQL desde PHP. Estoy ejecutando código como:

```
$query="SELECT * from pedidos";
    $rs_pedidos=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
    $pedidos=mysqli_fetch_array($rs_pedidos);

    for($i=0; $i<(count($pedidos)-1); $i++){
          
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$pedidos[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
```

pero me da undefined offset y no sé a qué se debe. Si pongo un sólo campo, por ejemplo,

```
$query="SELECT IdPedido from pedidos";
```

sólo me devuelve el primer IdPedido. Yo realmente necesito saber simplemente la longitud de la tabla y lo que tenía pensado era que me devolviera, por ejemplo, todos los IdPedido y luego hacerle un count($array) para poder tener la longitud de la misma. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Longitud de la tabla? ¿Te refieres a la cantidad de pedidos? Bastaría con `SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM pedidos`

Comment: ```    $query="SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM pedidos WHERE=1";
    $rs_pedidos=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
    var_dump($rs_pedidos); ```

Lo estoy haciendo con ese código pero el var_dump me sale false y no me muestra el total de pedidos. Esa misma sentencia en el SQL sí que me funciona. ¿Dónde está el error?

Comment: ¿Por qué le pusiste `WHERE = 1`? Prueba eso en PhpMyAdmin y vas a ver el error.

Comment: En PHPMyAdmin con el WHERE=1 me devuelve la longitud de las tablas perfectamente. Estoy probando en PHP con este código ahora, si el WHERE=1

```   $query="SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM pedidos";
    $rs_pedidos=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
    $pedidos=mysqli_fetch_row($rs_pedidos);
    var_dump($rs_pedidos);```

y ahora me muestra esto object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } ?> pero no la longitud de la tabla correspondiente.

Comment: Claro, porque estás mostrando el contenido de la consulta (recurso de MySQL), no el resultado: `$pedidos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_pedidos); var_dump($pedidos);`

Comment: Si lo lees así: `$pedidos=mysqli_fetch_row($rs_pedidos); ` puedes obtener el dato así: `echo $pedidos[0];`, y si lo pones así: `$pedidos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_pedidos);` la forma de obtener el valor es así: `echo $pedidos['total'];` asumiendo que el alias de la columna es `total`. Es la diferencia entre `fetch_row` y `fetch_assoc`  ya explicada aquí en alguna pregunta.